# First if statement keeps running even when false

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I've run into a problem with my if statements, been going over them and using console logs to make sure my variable which was declared before hand changes to a certain number when a div is hovered over, and the variable does change.

However for some reason the statements that should trigger when the variable is equal to a certain value doesn't change, it keeps running the first IF and I can't seem to figure out why, here is my syntax:

```
$('.work_thumbs').click(function()
{
    $('#shadow').fadeTo(200, 0.7);
    $('#image_holder').delay(200).show();

    if (thumbCheck = 1) {
                $('#image_holder').append('<img     style="cursor:pointer" class="holder_contents"     src="file:///C:/Users/Martin/martin_bodger/images/hi_res_images/ccda_exhibit.jpg">');

        } else if (thumbCheck = 2) {
                $('#image_holder').append('<img     style="cursor:pointer" class="holder_contents"     src="file:///C:/Users/Martin/martin_bodger/images/hi_res_images/yourock.png">');

        } else if (thumbCheck = 3) {
                $('#image_holder').append('<img     style="cursor:pointer" class="holder_contents"     src="file:///C:/Users/Martin/martin_bodger/images/hi_res_images/visualsynopsisposter.png">'    );

        } else if (thumbCheck = 4) {
                $('#image_holder').append('<img     style="cursor:pointer" class="holder_contents"     src="file:///C:/Users/Martin/martin_bodger/images/hi_res_images/awesome.jpg">');

        } else if (thumbCheck = 5) {
                $('#image_holder').append('<img     style="cursor:pointer" class="holder_contents"     src="file:///C:/Users/Martin/martin_bodger/images/hi_res_images/gameover.png">');

        } else {
                $('#image_holder').append('<img style="cursor:pointer" class="holder_contents" src="file:///C:/Users/Martin/martin_bodger/images/hi_res_images/whereisbill.png">');

        }

});
```

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
if (thumbCheck == 1)
```

that is, `==` (comparison) instead of `=` (assignment).

Answer (score 3):

use `==` **comparison operator** instead of `=` **assign operator**

```
thumbCheck == 1
```

not

```
thumbCheck = 1
```

Comment: Yeah sorry noticed it the moment I posted this question and then couldn't delete it, I feel like a bit of a tit haha

Answer (score 1):

The existing answers are correct (change the assignment `=` to comparison `==`), but for future reference you can solve simple issues like this using the freely available jslint and jshint tools;

- http://www.jshint.com/: copy your code in, click "using jQuery" and "Lint". It will say "Expected a conditional expression and instead saw an assignment", and also points out that you're not using strict mode and that `thumbCheck` hasn't been defined in this snippet.
- http://www.jslint.com/: is a much stricter alternative (jshint was built from this to be more easy going). You'll see a lot more issues here, but when you're getting started, it can be a bit overwhelming, and it's a bit pushy with its ideas about good style.